# Images don't display in ie9 when inserted using ajax and innerHTML, until users right clicks on and clicks "Show Pictures"

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-9, innerhtml

I was upgrading a wesbite to work with IE9 (I *really* hate IE), and after much fiddling it all finally worked, except that when inserting html into the page using code like the below, none of the pictures would display.

```
$("#div").innerHTML(htmlToInsertWithImgTags);
```

The inserted HTML looked a little like this:

[image: IE9 not showing pictures in html inserted using Ajax and innerHTML]

If you right clicked on any of the img's and then clicked on "Show Pictures", they all magically appeared, like below:

[image: IE9 showing pictures]

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to a trust setting in Internet Explorer, but if the image's you want to insert are already present on the web page, then internet explorer trusts the new content and shows the pictures.

So we got round this problem but adding code like the following (I'm aware this isn't good html) to the static part of the page, and then when this picture was inserted using Ajax and innerHTML eveything worked as you would expect.

```
<img url="redcircle.gif" style="display:none" />
```